# js как ответ поместить в массив для дальнейшей обработки

Tags: javascript, json

```
    <script>
        function search_inn_api()
        {
            var url = "https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/findById/party";
            var token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            var query = document.getElementById("wtp_inn").value;

            var options = {
                method: "POST",
                mode: "cors",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": "Token " + token
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({query: query})
            };

            fetch(url, options)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(result =>  console.log(result))
                .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
        }
    </script>
```

В консольке всё отображается, и даже если вместо console.log(result) написать alert(result). Результат есть. Но я не понимаю как мне работать с данными.

Например пытался.

```
document.getElementById("wtp_orgname").value = response.suggestions[0].value;
```

и результат пустой.

JSON Ответ сервака прикладываю.

```
{"suggestions":[{"value":"АКЦИОНЕРНОЕ ОБЩЕСТВО \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\"","unrestricted_value":"АКЦИОНЕРНОЕ ОБЩЕСТВО \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\"","data":{"kpp":"773601001","capital":null,"management":{"name":"Ковалев Андрей Викторович","post":"ГЕНЕРАЛЬНЫЙ ДИРЕКТОР","disqualified":null},"founders":null,"managers":null,"predecessors":null,"successors":null,"branch_type":"MAIN","branch_count":2,"source":null,"qc":null,"hid":"6775c00f3f38d8ad9dc54838e151a20cf9d68d557bfa4cf13c27573b9ef5d3af","type":"LEGAL","state":{"status":"ACTIVE","code":null,"actuality_date":1609459200000,"registration_date":1112313600000,"liquidation_date":null},"opf":{"type":"2014","code":"12267","full":"Непубличное акционерное общество","short":"НАО"},"name":{"full_with_opf":"АКЦИОНЕРНОЕ ОБЩЕСТВО \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\"","short_with_opf":null,"latin":null,"full":"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ","short":null},"inn":"7736520080","ogrn":"1057746557329","okpo":"76469930","okato":"45293554000","oktmo":"45397000000","okogu":"4210014","okfs":"16","okved":"35.14","okveds":null,"authorities":null,"documents":null,"licenses":null,"finance":null,"address":{"value":"г Москва, ул Вавилова, д 9","unrestricted_value":"117312, г Москва, Академический р-н, ул Вавилова, д 9","data":{"postal_code":"117312","country":"Россия","country_iso_code":"RU","federal_district":"Центральный","region_fias_id":"0c5b2444-70a0-4932-980c-b4dc0d3f02b5","region_kladr_id":"7700000000000","region_iso_code":"RU-MOW","region_with_type":"г Москва","region_type":"г","region_type_full":"город","region":"Москва","area_fias_id":null,"area_kladr_id":null,"area_with_type":null,"area_type":null,"area_type_full":null,"area":null,"city_fias_id":"0c5b2444-70a0-4932-980c-b4dc0d3f02b5","city_kladr_id":"7700000000000","city_with_type":"г Москва","city_type":"г","city_type_full":"город","city":"Москва","city_area":"Юго-западный","city_district_fias_id":null,"city_district_kladr_id":null,"city_district_with_type":"Академический р-н","city_district_type":"р-н","city_district_type_full":"район","city_district":"Академический","settlement_fias_id":null,"settlement_kladr_id":null,"settlement_with_type":null,"settlement_type":null,"settlement_type_full":null,"settlement":null,"street_fias_id":"25f8f29b-b110-40ab-a48e-9c72f5fb4331","street_kladr_id":"77000000000092400","street_with_type":"ул Вавилова","street_type":"ул","street_type_full":"улица","street":"Вавилова","house_fias_id":"758acce9-d44c-4b52-af14-6a637618d788","house_kladr_id":"7700000000009240067","house_type":"д","house_type_full":"дом","house":"9","block_type":null,"block_type_full":null,"block":null,"entrance":null,"floor":null,"flat_fias_id":null,"flat_type":null,"flat_type_full":null,"flat":null,"flat_area":null,"square_meter_price":null,"flat_price":null,"postal_box":null,"fias_id":"758acce9-d44c-4b52-af14-6a637618d788","fias_code":"77000000000000009240067","fias_level":"8","fias_actuality_state":"0","kladr_id":"7700000000009240067","geoname_id":"524901","capital_marker":"0","okato":"45293554000","oktmo":"45397000","tax_office":"7736","tax_office_legal":"7736","timezone":"UTC+3","geo_lat":"55.7042927","geo_lon":"37.5860935","beltway_hit":"IN_MKAD","beltway_distance":null,"metro":[{"name":"Ленинский проспект","line":"Калужско-Рижская","distance":0.3},{"name":"Площадь Гагарина","line":"МЦК","distance":0.3},{"name":"Воробьёвы горы","line":"Сокольническая","distance":1.9}],"qc_geo":"0","qc_complete":null,"qc_house":null,"history_values":null,"unparsed_parts":null,"source":"117312, ГОРОД МОСКВА, УЛ. ВАВИЛОВА, 9","qc":"0"}},"phones":null,"emails":null,"ogrn_date":1112313600000,"okved_type":"2014","employee_count":null}},{"value":"\"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ - ТЕХНИЧЕСКИЙ ЦЕНТР\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, УЛ СМОЛЬНАЯ)","unrestricted_value":"\"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ - ТЕХНИЧЕСКИЙ ЦЕНТР\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, УЛ СМОЛЬНАЯ)","data":{"kpp":"774343001","capital":null,"management":null,"founders":null,"managers":null,"predecessors":null,"successors":null,"branch_type":"BRANCH","branch_count":0,"source":null,"qc":null,"hid":"7eb1fad07ed585fafa096a43d4576d74c36c5f6f799ab540466da06104c438f8","type":"LEGAL","state":{"status":"ACTIVE","code":null,"actuality_date":1609459200000,"registration_date":null,"liquidation_date":null},"opf":{"type":"2014","code":"30002","full":"Филиал юридического лица","short":"Филиал"},"name":{"full_with_opf":"\"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ - ТЕХНИЧЕСКИЙ ЦЕНТР\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, УЛ СМОЛЬНАЯ)","short_with_opf":"\"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ - ТЕХНИЧЕСКИЙ ЦЕНТР\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, УЛ СМОЛЬНАЯ)","latin":null,"full":"\"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ - ТЕХНИЧЕСКИЙ ЦЕНТР\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, УЛ СМОЛЬНАЯ)","short":"\"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ - ТЕХНИЧЕСКИЙ ЦЕНТР\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, УЛ СМОЛЬНАЯ)"},"inn":"7736520080","ogrn":"1057746557329","okpo":null,"okato":null,"oktmo":null,"okogu":null,"okfs":null,"okved":null,"okveds":null,"authorities":null,"documents":null,"licenses":null,"finance":null,"address":{"value":"г Москва, ул Смольная, д 24А","unrestricted_value":"125445, г Москва, р-н Ховрино, ул Смольная, д 24А","data":{"postal_code":"125445","country":"Россия","country_iso_code":"RU","federal_district":"Центральный","region_fias_id":"0c5b2444-70a0-4932-980c-b4dc0d3f02b5","region_kladr_id":"7700000000000","region_iso_code":"RU-MOW","region_with_type":"г Москва","region_type":"г","region_type_full":"город","region":"Москва","area_fias_id":null,"area_kladr_id":null,"area_with_type":null,"area_type":null,"area_type_full":null,"area":null,"city_fias_id":"0c5b2444-70a0-4932-980c-b4dc0d3f02b5","city_kladr_id":"7700000000000","city_with_type":"г Москва","city_type":"г","city_type_full":"город","city":"Москва","city_area":"Северный","city_district_fias_id":null,"city_district_kladr_id":null,"city_district_with_type":"р-н Ховрино","city_district_type":"р-н","city_district_type_full":"район","city_district":"Ховрино","settlement_fias_id":null,"settlement_kladr_id":null,"settlement_with_type":null,"settlement_type":null,"settlement_type_full":null,"settlement":null,"street_fias_id":"7a6c6114-9eba-4bfd-bfcb-c562d67f3da3","street_kladr_id":"77000000000268200","street_with_type":"ул Смольная","street_type":"ул","street_type_full":"улица","street":"Смольная","house_fias_id":"7ea5e643-906b-4b5a-a26f-ef0f34a32d89","house_kladr_id":"7700000000026820079","house_type":"д","house_type_full":"дом","house":"24А","block_type":null,"block_type_full":null,"block":null,"entrance":null,"floor":null,"flat_fias_id":null,"flat_type":null,"flat_type_full":null,"flat":null,"flat_area":null,"square_meter_price":null,"flat_price":null,"postal_box":null,"fias_id":"7ea5e643-906b-4b5a-a26f-ef0f34a32d89","fias_code":"77000000000000026820079","fias_level":"8","fias_actuality_state":"0","kladr_id":"7700000000026820079","geoname_id":"524901","capital_marker":"0","okato":"45277595000","oktmo":"45347000","tax_office":"7743","tax_office_legal":"7743","timezone":"UTC+3","geo_lat":"55.8605412","geo_lon":"37.4833089","beltway_hit":"IN_MKAD","beltway_distance":null,"metro":[{"name":"Беломорская","line":"Замоскворецкая","distance":0.7},{"name":"Речной вокзал","line":"Замоскворецкая","distance":0.8},{"name":"Ховрино","line":"Замоскворецкая","distance":2.0}],"qc_geo":"0","qc_complete":null,"qc_house":null,"history_values":null,"unparsed_parts":null,"source":"125445, ГОРОД МОСКВА, УЛ. СМОЛЬНАЯ, 24А","qc":"0"}},"phones":null,"emails":null,"ogrn_date":null,"okved_type":null,"employee_count":null}},{"value":"\"ЦЕНТР ДИСТАНЦИОННОГО ОБСЛУЖИВАНИЯ\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, Ш КАШИРСКОЕ)","unrestricted_value":"\"ЦЕНТР ДИСТАНЦИОННОГО ОБСЛУЖИВАНИЯ\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, Ш КАШИРСКОЕ)","data":{"kpp":"772443001","capital":null,"management":null,"founders":null,"managers":null,"predecessors":null,"successors":null,"branch_type":"BRANCH","branch_count":0,"source":null,"qc":null,"hid":"1548a339c1e84ade1292149c41e7c7177f58f776799a843b33dfe601ad2033d1","type":"LEGAL","state":{"status":"ACTIVE","code":null,"actuality_date":1609459200000,"registration_date":null,"liquidation_date":null},"opf":{"type":"2014","code":"30002","full":"Филиал юридического лица","short":"Филиал"},"name":{"full_with_opf":"\"ЦЕНТР ДИСТАНЦИОННОГО ОБСЛУЖИВАНИЯ\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, Ш КАШИРСКОЕ)","short_with_opf":"\"ЦЕНТР ДИСТАНЦИОННОГО ОБСЛУЖИВАНИЯ\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, Ш КАШИРСКОЕ)","latin":null,"full":"\"ЦЕНТР ДИСТАНЦИОННОГО ОБСЛУЖИВАНИЯ\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, Ш КАШИРСКОЕ)","short":"\"ЦЕНТР ДИСТАНЦИОННОГО ОБСЛУЖИВАНИЯ\" АКЦИОНЕРНОГО ОБЩЕСТВА \"МОСЭНЕРГОСБЫТ\" (Г МОСКВА, Г МОСКВА, Ш КАШИРСКОЕ)"},"inn":"7736520080","ogrn":"1057746557329","okpo":null,"okato":null,"oktmo":null,"okogu":null,"okfs":null,"okved":null,"okveds":null,"authorities":null,"documents":null,"licenses":null,"finance":null,"address":{"value":"г Москва, Каширское шоссе, д 110 к 4","unrestricted_value":"115582, г Москва, Орехово-Борисово Южное р-н, Каширское шоссе, д 110 к 4","data":{"postal_code":"115582","country":"Россия","country_iso_code":"RU","federal_district":"Центральный","region_fias_id":"0c5b2444-70a0-4932-980c-b4dc0d3f02b5","region_kladr_id":"7700000000000","region_iso_code":"RU-MOW","region_with_type":"г Москва","region_type":"г","region_type_full":"город","region":"Москва","area_fias_id":null,"area_kladr_id":null,"area_with_type":null,"area_type":null,"area_type_full":null,"area":null,"city_fias_id":"0c5b2444-70a0-4932-980c-b4dc0d3f02b5","city_kladr_id":"7700000000000","city_with_type":"г Москва","city_type":"г","city_type_full":"город","city":"Москва","city_area":"Южный","city_district_fias_id":null,"city_district_kladr_id":null,"city_district_with_type":"Орехово-Борисово Южное р-н","city_district_type":"р-н","city_district_type_full":"район","city_district":"Орехово-Борисово Южное","settlement_fias_id":null,"settlement_kladr_id":null,"settlement_with_type":null,"settlement_type":null,"settlement_type_full":null,"settlement":null,"street_fias_id":"fcbf0d82-176c-473f-80bb-b4048d03f9a0","street_kladr_id":"77000000000049600","street_with_type":"Каширское шоссе","street_type":"ш","street_type_full":"шоссе","street":"Каширское","house_fias_id":"1f897e75-6225-49a2-86a3-98c90eb2273c","house_kladr_id":"7700000000004960724","house_type":"д","house_type_full":"дом","house":"110","block_type":"к","block_type_full":"корпус","block":"4","entrance":null,"floor":null,"flat_fias_id":null,"flat_type":null,"flat_type_full":null,"flat":null,"flat_area":null,"square_meter_price":null,"flat_price":null,"postal_box":null,"fias_id":"1f897e75-6225-49a2-86a3-98c90eb2273c","fias_code":"77000000000000004960724","fias_level":"8","fias_actuality_state":"0","kladr_id":"7700000000004960724","geoname_id":"524901","capital_marker":"0","okato":"45296579000","oktmo":"45922000","tax_office":"7724","tax_office_legal":"7724","timezone":"UTC+3","geo_lat":"55.607803","geo_lon":"37.7138086","beltway_hit":"IN_MKAD","beltway_distance":null,"metro":[{"name":"Домодедовская","line":"Замоскворецкая","distance":0.3},{"name":"Орехово","line":"Замоскворецкая","distance":1.3},{"name":"Красногвардейская","line":"Замоскворецкая","distance":1.9}],"qc_geo":"0","qc_complete":null,"qc_house":null,"history_values":null,"unparsed_parts":null,"source":"115582, ГОРОД МОСКВА, Ш. КАШИРСКОЕ, ДОМ 110, КОРПУС 4","qc":"0"}},"phones":null,"emails":null,"ogrn_date":null,"okved_type":null,"employee_count":null}}]}
```

Comment: « Например пытался.» — где? В каком месте кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `response.text()` нужно вызвать `response.json()` и тогда можно будет работать с результатом как с объектом:

```
fetch(url, options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
        document.getElementById("wtp_orgname").value = result.suggestions[0].value;
    })
  .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
```